# Meaning of "soul" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, interpretation

> Ah! she said, triumphantly: the little boy hurts, doesn't it? I said, stonily, it might be a good idea if, instead of a psychiatrist, she stopped off
> one afternoon at **a delousing station**.
>
> Did I (with her eyes widely open) really think so?
> Yes: I thought so. A delousing station might, after all, be ever so much
> more helpful than some poor doctor trying, in a scheduled hour, to
> disentangle that **soul** of hers.
> How nice to say she had one.
> she had one. Oh stained a little and dirtied a little and cheap a little. But
> she had one.
>
> White and fluttery?
>
> White and fluttery and from the hand of God.
>
> she was delighted. A **soul**: an actual **soul**. No one, in years, had used the
> word. Were souls coming back, like **mahjong**? But it was such a waste,
> wasn't it, to have bothered giving her one. so superfluous. It was one of
> the least necessary things. A **soul**, how silly. Of what possible use could it
> be, except to get in the way and trip her, at critical moments, like a
> nightgown that was a bit too long?
>
> she was smiling, with her head somewhat to one side, tracing the rim of
> the martini glass with her finger.
>
> that was the trouble: they kept giving you things you didn,t need. They
> never gave you quite what you really needed. Enough guts, for example.
>
> Didn't she have her share?
>
> sadly, no. No she didn,t. she didn't have nearly enough. she could use
> more and more. she could use scads of it for what she wanted to do. she'd
> trade it in: one **soul**, slightly damaged, for its equivalent in **guts**. Did I
> know a buyer? someone interested in second-hand **souls**? someone who'd
> care to exchange? Really: she was serious. She was perfectly serious.
> She'd love to get rid of the damn thing; it was such a nuisance having one,
> and being expected to take care of it, when really there wasn't time, and
> there were so many other more important things which needed her
> constant attention.
>
> Was I still brooding about the little boy?

I don't get the meaning of the whole context clearly and I think it is because the meaning of "soul" is unclear to me.

Does "soul" in this context mean: one person or does it mean: her spirits? it is somehow unclear to me.
I think it means person, but in the phrase: to disentangle  that soul of hers, I thought it means: spirits.

The meaning of some other words in this context that I wrote in bold is also unclear to me and maybe because of that the meaning of this word is unclear to me.

Does "delousing station" means: some where without bad people?

Source: My face for the world to see by Alfred Hayes

Comment: The meaning of _soul_ is unclear to you because the writer is using it in an entirely new way, to express something that he hasn't made clear. Ditto _delousing station_. This appears to be from a work of fantasy, in a different world from ours, and it is almost certainly intentional that the reader will not at first undersatnd what some of the words mean. Mahjonhg is a game, which was popular in the West for a time. _Guts_ **probably** means "boldness, courage"; but it could be another word that the writer is using with a special meaning in the world of the story.

Comment: I don't think we can give an answer here.  You probalby need to have read the book to understand it.  Many words might have "hidden" meanings.  A delousing station is a place where you take a shower or bath in chemicals to kill body and hair lice.  But it is also the term used euphemistically by the Nazis for the gas chambers. "Soul" could be completly literal "Her spirit", but it could speaking or her personality or it could be somthing that only exists in the world of the story.  Literature.stackexchange might be better.

Comment: Around the start of the last century health checks were carried out in the largest cities of the UK and, "if lice were discovered, the infected person was sent to a cleansing station." [https://londonspulse.org/delousing-people/]." People with lice can get very irritable. Perhaps that's why he suggests she stops off at one. Without having read the novel, the dictionary meanings of 'soul' and 'guts' seem to work fine.